# Celery: Which are the queues consumed if the -Q option is not specified

Tags: python, celery

According to the [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-q), the `-Q/--queues` command line option can be used for:

> **-Q, --queues**
>
> List of queues to enable for this worker, separated by comma. By default all configured queues are enabled. Example: *-Q video,image*

However I don't understand what does it mean with *configured* queues here. Does this mean all queues known to Celery, including the default one? Or only the ones defined in the  [`task_queues`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-queues) config option? Does the [`task_create_missing_queues`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_create_missing_queues) option affect this?

Comment: If `-q` not provided Celery worker will pick the tasks from all the queues defined in the configuration. As far as I know, `task_create_missing_queues` is completely disjoint from `-q` option. You can always try running with these configurations to confirm the results.

Comment: With "all the queues defined in the configuration" you mean "all the tasks defined in `task_queues`", right?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't configured anything, it will consume from `celery` queue and you can as you can see from logs

```
celery worker -A t 

 -------------- celery@pavilion v4.0.2 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-79-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2017-06-09 10:39:14
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f15cf9cdfd0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

You can also configure celery to consume a set of queues by default like this

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue


app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', backend='rpc')
app.conf.task_queues = (Queue('foo'), Queue('bar'))
```

Now all workers will consume `foo`, `bar` queues by default.

```
-------------- [queues]
               .> bar              exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
               .> foo              exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

Comment: So even if I define a task pointing to the queue `bar` with `task_create_missing_queues=True`, the queue `bar` will not be listened to by default if I don't use the `-Q` option?

Comment: For me, even when I define `task_create_missing_queues=True` in the celeryconfig.py file, the tasks never start if the `queue` argument is passed to the `apply_async`. It is strange tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue where when I would execute

```
$ celery -A myCeleryConfig worker -Q myQueue2
```

I would get error

```
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Trying to select queue subset of ['myQueue2'], but queue 'myQueue2' isn't defined in the `task_queues` setting.
```

The documentation for the [task_queues](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-queues) setting was unclear to me. It does state

> If you really want to configure advanced routing, this setting should be a list of kombu.Queue objects the worker will consume from.

I wasn't sure what it meant by this. No code examples are provided in the documentation. But, thanks to @Chillar's response, I came to find that configuring

```py
app.conf.task_queues = (Queue('myQueue1'), Queue('myQueue2'))
```

solved the issue. I now see

```
-------------- [queues]
               .> myQueue1              exchange=myQueue1 key=myQueue1
               .> myQueue2              exchange=myQueue2 key=myQueue2
```

when I start the worker, indicating the queue is now registered.